# Can't find what's causing the error for unexpected end of input error

Tags: php, jquery

So I'm getting an unexpected end of input error on my document load function. I've looked this error up and I figured it must be missing some closing brackets somewhere, but I just can't seem to find them. Is there something else that could be causing this error?? I'm not used to jQuery syntax and I'm mixing a lot of it with php so it's kinda crazy and I'm afraid I'm unable to distinguish it correctly or it might be reading it weird.

The error is highlighting the first line: $(function(){

my code:

```
    $(function() {
        //Loading correct divs into place.
        $('#peerDiv').load('<?php if(isset($_GET['popup'])) echo "../../";?>incl/singleForms/returnPeer.php?company=<?php echo $companyID;?>&zoneID=&ipPeer=');
        $('#ingressDiv').load('<?php if(isset($_GET['popup'])) echo "../../";?>incl/singleForms/returnIngress.php?company=<?php echo $companyID; ?>&peerID=&peerView=');

        <?php
        if(isset($_GET['ipPeer'])){
            //Query that selects the zone and cacPool for the currently selected peer
            $qry = "SELECT zoneID, ipID FROM ipPeers WHERE peerName ='" . $_GET['ipPeer'] . "';";
            $qry_result = odbc_exec($admconn,$qry) or die("A database error has been detected. Err: returnIPPeer-1");
            while($row = odbc_fetch_array($qry_result)){                                
                $zoneID = $row['zoneID'];
                $ipID = $row['ipID'];

        ?>

        //Loading correct divs into place.
        $('#peerDiv').load('incl/singleForms/returnPeer.php?<?php if(!empty($_GET['ipPeer'])){ echo "enable=";}?>&company=<?php echo $companyID;?>&zoneID=<?php echo $zoneID; ?>&ipPeer=<?php echo $peerID;?>');
        $('#ingressDiv').load('incl/singleForms/returnIngress.php?enable=&company=<?php echo $companyID;  if(!empty($_GET['ipPeer'])){ echo "enable=";}?>&peerID=<?php echo $_GET['ipPeer'];?>&peerView=');

        //Highlighting correct values for select options.
        $("#zoneList").val('<?php echo $zoneID;?>');
        $("#ipAddExist").val('<?php echo $_GET['ipPeer'];?>');  
        $("#ingressList").val('<?php echo $_GET['ipPeer'];?>');
    });
    <?php }
    }?>
```

Comment: why are you injecting PHP into JS?

Comment: Output the generated javascript. Also you are open to SQL injections with this code.

Comment: I think, the problem is, you are not close your `$(function() {` with `});` at the end of the file.

Comment: Yes..And where are your `<script></script>` tags and exactly why are you injecting `PHP` into `JS` or vice versa?

Comment: **Note :** What you are doing there is bad practice to do things.Try to avoid it onwards.

Comment: Look in the console exactly that at which line you are getting error and there it is..You have problem in there..! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have closed your `$(function() {` inside the PHP `if` so if `isset($_GET['ipPeer'])` is NOT SET you never close the javascript properly

```
$(function() {
    //Loading correct divs into place.
    $('#peerDiv').load('<?php if(isset($_GET['popup'])) echo "../../";?>incl/singleForms/returnPeer.php?company=<?php echo $companyID;?>&zoneID=&ipPeer=');
    $('#ingressDiv').load('<?php if(isset($_GET['popup'])) echo "../../";?>incl/singleForms/returnIngress.php?company=<?php echo $companyID; ?>&peerID=&peerView=');

    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['ipPeer'])){
        //Query that selects the zone and cacPool for the currently selected peer
        $qry = "SELECT zoneID, ipID FROM ipPeers WHERE peerName ='" . $_GET['ipPeer'] . "';";
        $qry_result = odbc_exec($admconn,$qry) or die("A database error has been detected. Err: returnIPPeer-1");
        while($row = odbc_fetch_array($qry_result)){                                
            $zoneID = $row['zoneID'];
            $ipID = $row['ipID'];

    ?>

    //Loading correct divs into place.
    $('#peerDiv').load('incl/singleForms/returnPeer.php?<?php if(!empty($_GET['ipPeer'])){ echo "enable=";}?>&company=<?php echo $companyID;?>&zoneID=<?php echo $zoneID; ?>&ipPeer=<?php echo $peerID;?>');
    $('#ingressDiv').load('incl/singleForms/returnIngress.php?enable=&company=<?php echo $companyID;  if(!empty($_GET['ipPeer'])){ echo "enable=";}?>&peerID=<?php echo $_GET['ipPeer'];?>&peerView=');

    //Highlighting correct values for select options.
    $("#zoneList").val('<?php echo $zoneID;?>');
    $("#ipAddExist").val('<?php echo $_GET['ipPeer'];?>');  
    $("#ingressList").val('<?php echo $_GET['ipPeer'];?>');

//});  <- move from here
<?php }
}    //<- dont think this should be here either, but cannot see all your PHP code so thats a guess
?>   
});   // <- move to here
```

Comment: Thank you! I completely missed that and it's been driving me crazy.